# How to set a fixed distance between the label

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How can I adjust the label and layout so that the margin between the label is constant? I tried different options in the editor but nothing works. The size between the label is fixed. I don't know how to reduce it. Brought the code.

My function for auto add label into layout. Thank you for help.

```
def auto_label(self, number, color, text):

    test_label = QLabel()
    test_label.setScaledContents(True)
    test_label.setFixedWidth(50)
    test_label.setFixedHeight(50)
    #test_label.setSizePolicy(1, 10)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(14)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    test_label.setFont(font)
    test_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    if color == "blue":
        test_label.setStyleSheet('background: blue')
    if color == "red":
        test_label.setStyleSheet('background: red')
    if color == "gray":
        test_label.setStyleSheet('background: gray')
    if color == "green":
        test_label.setStyleSheet('background: green')
    if color == "yellow":
        test_label.setScaledContents(True)
        test_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/yu.png'))
    if color == "yellow1":
        test_label.setScaledContents(True)
        test_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/ya.png'))
    if color == "yellow2":
        test_label.setScaledContents(True)
        test_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/yo.png'))
    if color == "yellow3":
        test_label.setScaledContents(True)
        test_label.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/ye.png'))
    if color == "white":
        test_label.setStyleSheet('background: white')
    #self.centralwidget.resize(width, 50)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.insertWidget(number, test_label)
```

My UI code:

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(723, 367)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(10)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.inputLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
    font.setPointSize(50)
    self.inputLine.setFont(font)
    self.inputLine.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.inputLine.setInputMethodHints
        (QtCore.Qt.ImhPreferLowercase|QtCore.Qt.ImhPreferUppercase)
    self.inputLine.setText("")
    self.inputLine.setFrame(False)
    self.inputLine.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.inputLine.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
    self.inputLine.setObjectName("inputLine")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.inputLine, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.enterButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.enterButton.setObjectName("enterButton")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.enterButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

And image with problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From that description and the images, it is unclear what is the problem. Could you describe it more precisely? Which label, which margin? What is the desired state you want to achieve?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a valid [mre] and add an image of the expected behavior.

Comment: In Qt Designer, insert a *new* horizontal-layout at the top of the main vertical-layout (i.e. `verticalLayout_2`).  Then add two horizontal spacers to that new layout. Finally, drag and drop `horizontalLayout_2` *between* those two spacers. (The spacers will squeeze all the labels together in the middle with a fixed gap between them, which is determined by the spacing property of the layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QHboxLayout` for this purpose.

`QHboxLayout` provides same width for all it's children and auto adjusts the width of all children upon adding new child, in this case `QLabel` (unless modified)